# I am so close, logic not come easy to me, php selector

Tags: php, html

how do I get my image file selector "$filetwo"  to echo to only echo .jpg files.  "$filetwo" is picking up folder names.  i am loading a html link into the anchor tag src "$file" and trying to load an image link inside of anchor tag.  the folders i am pulling from will be static for the most part, for every html file there will be a picture to pair with in the same order

```
   <div class="content-area">
        <?php
        $dir ="clubPhotos/clubPhotosPageVault/"; // image folder name
        $dirtwo = "clubPhotos/";
        if (is_dir($dir)){
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
                $dhtwo = opendir($dirtwo);
                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                    $filetwo = readdir($dhtwo);
                    if($file=="." OR $file==".."){} else { 
                        ?>   <!---- its a loop [change the folder name on img path]----->                
                            <a href="clubPhotos/clubPhotosPageVault/<?php echo $file; ? 
                  >"><img  style="width: 260px;" src="clubPhotos/<?php echo $filetwo; ?>"></a> 
                            <br><h2>
        <?php  
                            if($filetwo=="." OR $filetwo==".."){} else { 
                                             
                                $basename = pathinfo($filetwo, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                                echo substr($basename, 0, 4);
                                            
                                echo substr($basename, 4); //substr() usage
                                // echo $basename;
                            }?>
                                                                           </h2>
        <?php
                                       }
                                  
                }
                closedir($dh);
                closedir($dh2);
            }
        } ?>
        </div><!--          CONTENT AREA-->
```

Comment: You should check if `$dirtwo . "/" . $filetwo` is a directory. If it is, skip it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing by reading from two different directories in parallel. The order that the files are returned is not well defined, so you can't expect that you'll get related files from each directory.

Comment: I thought I was, maybe in the wrong place, 
        if($filetwo=="." OR $filetwo==".."){
i thought maybe put $filetwo in an array?

Comment: the php page I am making, checks for number of html files, then displays and corresponding image, based on non random order and displays preset image and links it to the html page,  also takes apart the file name to display the title of the album sloppily

Comment: But the order that `readdir()` reads is essentially random.

Comment: Is there a term for what I am trying to emulate?  I know there must be a function or system that does all this for me, i am lacking the keyword to look it up.  i got fancy box but i want just a bit more automation.  Most of my albums have 80 pictures and I need about 75 pages, one for each album

Comment: Is there a relationship between the filenames in the two directories? So if there's `xxx.html` in one directory there's a corresponding `xxx.jpg` in the other.

Comment: "But the order that readdir() reads is essentially random -Barmar"    oh dear

Comment: Is there a relationship between the filenames in the two directories? So if there's xxx.html in one directory there's a corresponding xxx.jpg in the other. – 
Barmar
Yes, each album gets a page, an album picture and both of those are displayed on a album selection page in picture form, under each picture on the album selection page is the "name of the album" which is really the folder name with spaces

Comment: So instead of reading both directories, just read one directory. Then convert that filename to the corresponding name in the other directory.

Comment: That was the golden ticket.  Now how do I transverse the list backwards?  Is seem to display a- z  Id like it to be z-a. Thank you for you time

Comment: The order is just the order from the disk, which shouldn't be sorted at all. If you need a specific order, read all the filenames into an array and sort it.